# Simple GLSL example to render a 2d textured quad?

Tags: opengl, shaders

I would really love to add shader support in my game , although i can't seem to find a SIMPLE example on how to setup opengl for using shaders.

So i would like to ask : Does anyone knows if there are any SIMPLE examples for beginners ? (ie Rendering a simple 2d quad or something like that)

Comment: Sorry, but using shaders for the first time isn't "simple". It took me a while to get the hang of it and I still consider my use novice. My implementation is relatively simple if you'd like to browse my source: https://github.com/amplify91/RAW. The GLSL shaders are in res/raw and you should also look at the following classes: Shader, SpriteBatch, and GameRenderer. Good luck!

Comment: Glad I might help :) just keep looking at tutorials till you get it! Welcome to gamedev.SE!